# Can all administrative procedures except getting married or getting divorced be done online in Estonia?

Tags: internet

I have read this quote in http://www.businessinsider.com/guardtime-estonian-health-records-industrial-blockchain-bitcoin-2016-3:

> Mike Gault, co-founder and CEO of Guardtime, told Business Insider: "The only thing that you can’t do online in Estonia is get married or get divorced. Otherwise you don’t need to go to a government office."

Can all administrative procedures except getting married or getting divorced be done online in Estonia?

Comment: Define "administrative procedure"?

Comment: I would imagine so, since each citizen has a government-signed  public key

Comment: Is getting arrested an administrative procedure?

Comment: The Estonian [Administrative Procedure Act](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=328755) defines it as " activities conducted by an administrative authority (§ 8) upon issue of regulations (§ 88) or administrative acts (§§ 51 and 52), taking measures (§ 106) or entry into contracts under public law (§ 95)." I am not sure if that helps.

Comment: It would be funny if Estonian lawmakers specifically define "administrative procedure" such that this question is true. Citizen: "But sir, I was not able to do that online!!", official: "Ah! That's because that's not an administrative procedure!". :D

Comment: This site contains the component required for Estonia's digital society-https://e-estonia.com/ and this site-https://www.eesti.ee/eng/services/citizen lists out all digital services and forms required for the administrative procedures for an Estonian citizen.

Comment: Yay Denmark is way ahead of Estonia. We can get divorced online. And we can go to a church to get married, that is not a goverment office. For the rest we have online forms. The main question is why does this even matter? Each country does as it finds appropiate.

Comment: @Bent efficiency